# Monthly grouped data

Tags: mysql, php, pivot

OK! I've a table that looks like this: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf65c/1)

And I want to get some handlers to provide to my renderer php page, so that  the final result be like this:

```
+----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|                |           JANUARY          |           FEBRUARY         |
+  product_name  +---------------+------------+---------------+------------+
|                | Tt. quant_ton | AVG  value | Tt. quant_ton | AVG  value |
+----------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+
|     gravel     |       41      |   51.25    |      22       |   55.00    |
+----------------+---------------+------- ----+---------------+------- ----+
|      soil      |       23      |   29.90    |      10       |   13.00    |
+----------------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+
```

I don't know how to retrieve this data. I tried with [CASE THEN](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bf65c/8) but one case removes data from the other, leaving the table with blank fields.

Comment: It's better to do it in PHP, but here is code to generate the [_pivot_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pivoting-in-mariadb/) .

Comment: the code you mention is a litle farfetched to me, can you point me to a manual or book that will help me understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your CASE variant with some modifications. First you need to extend the `GROUP BY` with MONTH(date):

```
SELECT product_name,
  CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 1 THEN SUM(quant_ton) END AS JAN,
  CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 2 THEN SUM(quant_ton) END AS FEV
FROM tb_import
JOIN tb_cost
    ON tb_import.productid = tb_cost.productid
JOIN tb_sites
    ON tb_sites.site_num = tb_import.site_cd
JOIN tb_product
    ON tb_product.prod_id = tb_import.productid
GROUP BY product_name, MONTH(date)
```

If not MySQL will randomly pick one month for you. There's a lot to be said about this default setting (insane comes to mind:-), but look up `sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` for ways around it.

As you can see now you will get null for non-matching months:

```
product_name    JAN    FEV
gravel          41     (null)
gravel          (null) 22
soil            23     (null)
soil            (null) 10
```

By picking - for example - max of JAN and FEV you will get rid of those

```
SELECT product_name, max(JAN), max(FEV)
FROM (
    SELECT product_name,
        CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 1 THEN SUM(quant_ton) END AS JAN,
        CASE WHEN MONTH(date) = 2 THEN SUM(quant_ton) END AS FEV
    FROM tb_import
    JOIN tb_cost
        ON tb_import.productid = tb_cost.productid
    JOIN tb_sites
        ON tb_sites.site_num = tb_import.site_cd
    JOIN tb_product
        ON tb_product.prod_id = tb_import.productid
    GROUP BY product_name, MONTH(date)
) as t
GROUP BY product_name;

product_name    max(JAN)    max(FEV)
gravel          41          22
soil            23          10
```

However, the pivoting is only a presentation of the result. I would choose a query like:

```
SELECT product_name,
       MONTH(date),
       SUM(quant_ton) 
FROM tb_import
JOIN tb_cost
    ON tb_import.productid = tb_cost.productid
JOIN tb_sites
    ON tb_sites.site_num = tb_import.site_cd
JOIN tb_product
    ON tb_product.prod_id = tb_import.productid
GROUP BY product_name, MONTH(date)
ORDER BY product_name, MONTH(date);
```

and then format the result in the presentation layer of the application.

Comment: Do you mean to create a view like:

Comment: just ignore the above comment, pressed enter by mistake and can't edit it! Do you mean to create a `view` and get the values from there?

Comment: No, just retrieve the result from the last query. When you loop over the result set you create a structure that can be presented in your report (or whatever the target is).

Comment: Well I did what you said. In PHP I looped thru the result and then created one array for each product_name. Now I'm trying create a key-value for each month that has no data, so I can order it, to automatically insert it in a table. But I'm having trouble in finding a valid algorithm.

Comment: If you order the result (modified the answer), you can check if there is a new product. If it is create a new array and add the sum in first pos, if not add sum in the pos that corresponds to the month. At the end each product will have an array with sums that you can output in your report

Comment: Finally did it! In a simplistic manner what I did was, (1st) make the query as you said it.  (2nd) Did a for loop to retrieve all rows. (3rd) Then made a second for loop to separate each by its product_name. (4th) Afterwards did a sweep in each product_name array to order it by index number relative to month, (5th) then filled the missing months with zeros, et voilá I have arrays for each product to pass to the render page! Thanks Lennart,  for pointing me to the SQL code and Rick James for "It's better to do it in PHP". PS - I know that's a lot of loops, but even so, I think I have an O(n).

Comment: Since the resultset is ordered you can do some of the work while retrieving the result. Initialize current_product to the empty string, then in the retrive loop check if product_name != current_product. If it is you know this is the next product and you can allocate a new array for it.

Comment: in my case the products are standard and quantified in a table, so no need to lookout for new products.